# scikit : Wrong prediction for this case

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have written a sample code below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv 
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB



text = ["this is dog" , "this is bull dog" , "this is jack"]



countVector  = CountVectorizer()
countmatrix = countVector.fit_transform(text)

print countVector.vocabulary_
print countmatrix.toarray()

tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
idfX = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(countmatrix)

#print tfidf_transformer.vocabulary_
print idfX.toarray()

clf = MultinomialNB().fit( idfX, ["dog" , "dog" , "human"])

test = ["this is jack"]

testCountMatrix = countVector.transform(test)
testidfX = tfidf_transformer.transform(testCountMatrix)

print testidfX.toarray()
print clf.predict(testidfX)
```

For above result I am getting `"Dog"` as prediction even though trained data is identical to test data.

where am I wrong on this ?

Comment: That is weird. Have you tried other classifiers as well?

Comment: I have to try .. Can you please tell me if code is correct ?

Comment: @cfh : I tried SGDClassifier and it is giving me correct results ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected (or at least not so unexpected) behavior with the code you have written: you have two instances labeled as `dog` in which you have the term `this is`, so the algorithm learns that `this is` is related to `dog`. It might not be what you're after, but it's a valid association (would you not be susceptible to making the same mistake if you didn't know English?). You're overfitting the training data. A default `SVC()` will also give the same result.

Try making the last training instance `this is jack jack` for example, then it will give `human` for `this is jack`, because the word `jack` will be more "powerful" as an identifier for `human`.

Another way is to set the `alpha` parameter in your classifier:

```
clf = MultinomialNB(alpha=0.1).fit( idfX, ["dog" , "dog", "human"])
```

This will correctly classify all of your own training instances.

Look into scikit's grid searches for optimizing the hyperparameters of your predictors. Using the default is almost never the best thing you can do.

Comment: Thanks .. But only after adding ( alpha = 0.1 ) it works . can you explain me what it does ? I tried reading it but didnt understand - Regularization of terms ?

Comment: @voila - it's a smoothing parameter, and it acts similar to regularization. You can see how it is used in the source code: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/naive_bayes.py

Comment: @voila: I think a better reference than the source code is this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing